# Weighting a list in Python does not sum to the intended value

Tags: python, weighted

I want to take the elements of `List3` which describes the amount of production Days available at each month of the year, and weight this together with the annual production in `List1` to accomplish a monthly production volume. My code is:

```
List3 = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,19,31,30,31]
List = [5150]

for i in xrange(len(List3)):
    j = List3[i]
    g = g+j

for i in xrange(len(List)):
    a = List[i]/g
    for j in xrange(len(List3)):
        print (a*List3[j])
```

where `a` describes how much production is made *each day*, so multiplying this with the elements of `List3[j]` for each month ought to provide the total monthly production.

However, running this program yields the monthly production:

> 434 392 434 420 434 420 434 434 266 434 420 434

which sums to 4956. But the annual production in `List3` was 5150 units. Hence, there is a discrepancy of 154 units between the annual production and the sum of the monthly production.

Can somebody see where I have done wrong? I remember that I have remade this code earlier to become that the sum of the monthly production at most differed approximately 10 units from the annual production, which would suffice. I don't remember how I did however.

Regards,

Comment: you need to replace g by float(g)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by rounding. In Python 2, this line is integer division:

```
a = List[i]/g
```

Here's a simple experimental workflow with the interactive interpreter to illustrate the issue:

```
>>> l3 = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,19,31,30,31]
>>> l = [5150]
>>> g = sum(l3)
>>> g
354
>>> a = l[0] / g
>>> a
14
>>> sum(a*e for e in l3)
4956
>>> a = l[0] / float(g)
>>> a
14.548022598870057
>>> sum(a*e for e in l3)
5149.999999999999
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this issue. I thought all numbers were interpreted as floats, unless otherwise stated and not the other way around. This is very useful to know!

Comment: Also nice to see someone coding in a more pythonic way. Now I can omit that dreadful loop to achieve g, and the `sum(a*e for e in l3)` looks very nice indeed.